# Getting banks layer from OpenStreetMap with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, spatialite

I downloaded Mexico City data from with QGIS, and I want to make a layer only with the banks. When I select "Export topology from SpatialLite", it shows a long list of all the properties and asks me to pick the properties I want to create a layer, but I don't know what property I can use to know if a building is a bank to make a layer of banks.

[image]

Is there a property that tells if a building is a bank?

Answer (score 8):

Banks are tagged as [amenity=bank](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dbank) so you need to look for the amenity key.

This tag can appear on nodes and ways. This means that you will not only get buildings but also individual POIs. Keep in mind that in OSM properties don't have to be added to buildings, adding a single POI node inside a building is perfectly valid. In fact this approach is necessary for all buildings that contain multiple POIs.

If you are also interested in individual ATMs outside of banks then take a look at [amenity=atm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Datm), too.

Comment: You should add the `name` tag as well, to get something usable for rendering labels.

Comment: Yes and maybe `brand`, too.

Comment: Thaks, for answering. I have another similar question. Do you know how can I know if something is a gas station?

Comment: A search at the OSM wiki for "gas station" directly leads to [amenity=fuel](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel).